# Angular Frontend Get Files from Java Rest Backend

Tags: java, arrays, angularjs, rest, jersey

I want to fill a File Array in my (Angular) front-end with files from my (Java, Jersey 2, RESTful) back-end.

I know how to upload a file from the frontend to the server and I know how to download a file from the backend - no problem.

I tried:

- to build a response with the content of a File Array, that results in just receiving the server path of the file
- to send an octet-stream and to store the data in a blob, but I cant convert the blob to a File for my File array that I wanna fill